# How to extract a particular value in array of cookies?

Tags: objective-c, cookies

I am having an array of cookies, in which I have to traverse through and retrieve only particular value of a cookie name "token". when I traverse the array, how am I suppose to find out that the value of the cookie is of that particular cookie name?

My Cookie look like -

```
("<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:\"_#name\" value:\"value of this cookie\" expiresDate:2018-05-16 15:30:55 +0000 created:2015-08-20 15:30:55 +0000 (4.61777e+08) sessionOnly:FALSE domain:\"X.X.X.X\" path:\"/\" isSecure:FALSE>",
"<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:\"_#name\" value:\"value of this cookie\" expiresDate:2018-05-16 15:30:55 +0000 created:2015-08-20 15:30:55 +0000 (4.61777e+08) sessionOnly:FALSE domain:\"X.X.X.X\" path:\"/\" isSecure:FALSE>",
"<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:\"name\" value:\"value\" expiresDate:2015-08-20 15:40:38 +0000 created:2015-08-20 15:30:38 +0000 (4.61777e+08) sessionOnly:FALSE domain:\"X.X.X.X\" path:\"/\" isSecure:FALSE>",
"<NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:\"token\" value:\"value of the cookie\" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-08-20 15:30:33 +0000 (4.61777e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:\"X.X.X.X\" path:\"/\" isSecure:TRUE>")
```

I want to extract the value of "token".

Comment: how does your array look like?

Comment: added cookie array for reference.

Comment: You might find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899893/nshttpcookiestorage-array-parsing-out-the-value